# Can't uninstall a cumulative update/security update in Windows 10 22H2 is this completely normal?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, uninstall

So after finding out about window's recent cumulative update KB5028166 it appeared to have had bugs along with it such as stuttering, slowdowns.

But they are working on a bug fix that will come soon and im waiting for that but the question is "Is it completely normal if i cant uninstall the cumulative update?"

I tried the Uninstall Updates option in Update History and it didnt appear to have a uninstall button but the others do.

And i also tried the command in command prompt "wusa /uninstall /kb:5028166" and it said something along the lines of

(KB5028166) is required by your computer and cannot be uninstalled. i clicked OK and did not do anything after that.

Did i mess up something or it just didnt allow me to uninstall the update and left Windows 10 harmless and untouched?

I just figured waiting for the next bug fix for the issues to stop and not do anything to my PC since i just did a reinstall on it 18 days ago.  lol

And also PC's running fine no said "stuttering nor slowdowns" im just worried if it also had an effect on my PC.

I think my rollback/uninstall optiom was stripped because i did do DISM RestoreHealth and Disk Cleanup to clean the Windows Update Files.

Although i wasnt able to uninstall it because its not allowed i am waiting for the hotfix though. Just incase i wont come across the issues they said i'll come across?

Note that i didnt do any further tweaking after pressing ok as windows didnt allow me to uninstall the Cumulative Update/Security Update all i did afterwards was restarting the pc to check if messed up something.

Comment: Service Stack Update like KB5028166 cannot be removed

Comment: Ohhhh.. so security updates/service stack updates cannot be removed?? But i checked on my other oc and the uninstall option was available there though? it also had KB5028166 and can be uninstalled.

Comment: [You can remove the LCU not the SSU by running “DISM /online /get-packages”](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/july-11-2023-kb5028166-os-builds-19044-3208-and-19045-3208-eab49ea6-3133-41c8-845f-a14a329c6c20) if you read the documentation your method of uninstalling it isn’t supported. The performance issues are likely connected to the LCU not the SSU anyways

Comment: Neat but im not really planning to do that im just gonna wait for the hotfixes rather than risking my Windows 10.

Comment: Ok….We’ll I am going to submit an answer so this question cannot simply be deleted for everyone’s else benefit

Comment: The thing is it wasnt the Service Stack Update i wasnt trying to uninstall it was THE latest cumulative update. But how can my other pc have an Uninstall option when going in Uninstall Updates and mine doesnt for the latest cumulative update.

Comment: Read the supporting documentation I linked to in my comment which specifically indicates you can’t uninstall the cumulative update using Windows Update Standalone Installer due to the included SSU content.

Answer (score 2):

> And i also tried the command in command prompt "wusa /uninstall /kb:5028166" and it said something along the lines of
> (KB5028166) is required by your computer and cannot be uninstalled. i clicked OK and did not do anything after that.

This is intentional this particular cumulative update (Latest Cumulative Update) also includes a Servicing Stack Update (SSU) which cannot be removed.

You can identify and remove the LCU by running:

```
DISM /online /get-packages
```

Then run the command against the identified package

```
/Remove-Package {/PackageName:<name_in_image> | /PackagePath:<path_to_cabfile>}
```

> I think my rollback/uninstall option was stripped because i did do DISM RestoreHealth and Disk Cleanup to clean the Windows Update Files.

The option wouldn’t be there regardless if you had run it or not but running the cleanup routine very well much prevent you from removing the LCU package in question.

Source:

- [July 11, 2023—KB5028166 (OS Builds 19044.3208 and 19045.3208)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/july-11-2023-kb5028166-os-builds-19044-3208-and-19045-3208-eab49ea6-3133-41c8-845f-a14a329c6c20)
- [/Remove-Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-operating-system-package-servicing-command-line-options?view=windows-11#remove-package)

Comment: I did do the cleanup routine 2 times so it could've cemented my fate.

Comment: But nonetheless i didnt come across the said stuttering , slowdown issues caused by the LCU and also by Windows not allowing the uninstallation did it delete anything? before they cancelled the operation? Am i completely fine? Is Windows 10 untouched just like it was before i did all this?

Comment: I found plenty of evidence that the LCU is to blame. Besides it’s the only thing you can remove since the SSU cannot be removed. Your other questions contained within a temporary comment are beyond the scope of your immediate question in my opinion and won’t be addressed by this focused answer

Comment: By `/Remove-Package {/PackageName:<name_in_image> | /PackagePath:<path_to_cabfile>}` did you mean `DISM /online /Remove-Package {/PackageName:<name_in_image> | /PackagePath:<path_to_cabfile>}` ? I tryed to run `DISM /online  /Remove-Package /PackageName:Package_for_ServicingStack_3205~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~19041.3205.1.1` but I got "Error: 0x800f0825" googling which I found it means "permanent package cannot be uninstalled". It's a mess, because last bunch of WinUpdates prevent a program I need to work!

Comment: You **cannot** remove the servicing stack update only the LSU. So you’re trying to remove a package that cannot be removed from your system. **My answer makes this explicitly clear.** Your issues are absolutely not caused by SSU. If you have a question asked your own detailed question